# paste and copy demonstrations to slide shows

Tags: slideshows

I'm new on Mathematica, I started to work with it yesterday and this software is simply amazing!

However I'm having the following trouble which I couldn't find any solution on internet (I use a linux distro):

I went to [Wolfram demonstration page](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SecantAndTangentLines/) and I clicked on "download author code".

[image]

I opened the file: SecantAndTangentLines-author.nb

I didn't see any graph or code. Then I clicked on update thumbnail and snapshot and enable dynamics bottom

[image]

Mathematica gave me a lot of errors:

[image]
How can I get the author code to use in my slide show? How can I paste and copy dynamic graphs in Mathematica?

Thanks

Edit: I've already solved the problem and the graph is working. However, I couldn't see where is the author code.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Looks like the function `f` is undefined.  Try running the initialization code. -- I think you'll need to be a little patient and start by learning the basics first.  Cutting and pasting other programmer's dynamic code often requires you to be pretty knowledgeable about *Mathematica* programming.  It's usually much more difficult than cutting and pasting images into a text editor, esp. if you're getting your input from the Demonstrations site. The authors often write their programs as though they will run in an isolated, stand-alone environment.

Comment: In the downloaded *.nb file, you should evaluate the first cell that contains some needed definitions such as the one for `f`. You can see those definitions by double clicking on the cell bracket on the right of the "Initialization" cell group.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I solved the problem, thank you. However I don't know where I can find the author code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Wolfram Demonstration page, click on "Download Demonstration (.CDF)". Save the file "SecantAndTangentLines.cdf". Open this file with *Mathematica*, and click on the gray "Download Source Code >>" button below RELATED LINKS and above PERMANENT CITATION. Now save the file "SecantAndTangentLines-source.nb". Opening this second file will show all the code used to make the demonstration. Demonstration files ending in "-source.nb" are the ones you want.

Comment: My understanding is that OP has done that already; My guess is that he/she just needs to evaluate the initialization cells that contain needed definitions.

Comment: @MarcoB When I open the *-source.nb*, and execute the code block, the demonstration works with no errors. In the OP I can only find references to *-author*.nb files in his text and in the images included. I've never used such files, only the the source.nb files, which have always worked for me...

Comment: @MarcoB I solved the problem, the graph is working. However I don't know where I can find the source code.